# Xamarin.Forms Editor.TextChanged event does not fire

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get the value of an `Editor` in my share code with `Xamarin.Forms`.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Editor/

```
Editor introduce = new Editor { Text = "", BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("F0C640"), TextColor = Color.White, FontSize = 10, HeightRequest = 50 };
introduce.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("introduce");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.NewTextValue);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.OldTextValue);
};
```

But the event is never trigger...
When is it supposed to be trigger? I guessed it was when you focus out the `Editor` block and the content of it changed but it doesn't work on my tests...

I also tried the `Completed` event but still not triggered.

```
introduce.Completed += (sender, e) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("introduce");
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure but try this: run it in the iOS simulator and press the DONE button after changing the text. I think it only gets fired then.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I don't have any DONE button :(

Comment: No button like in this image on the lower right? http://i.stack.imgur.com/PYmpo.png

Comment: Oh sorry. Actually it's an Editor field so this button is to go to a new line like that: http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/typing-line-breaks-in-imessages.jpg

Comment: The event should be fired as you enter/delete characters. What platform are you seeing this issue on? I tested this on both iOS and Android and it was working fine on the latest Forms version (2.3.2.127). Update Forms to this version if you have not already and if you still experience this issue, please provide a [reproduction project](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).